# Shopee XPath scraping follower count into Google Sheet

Tags: html, xpath, google-sheets, screen-scraping

What I want it to shows: Products & Followers

1. It will shows 29.10.2020 Followers and Products then it will stop the update on the end of the day
2. What I can get is just the Followers and I want to remove the words ( Followers ) Just need the numbers
3. The Product Count I can't get I have no idea how to do it.

The only formulas that I know how: `=index(IMPORTXML(B5,"//*[contains(@class,'shop-page')]"),9)`

https://shopee.ph/fitme.ph

**https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QQyW8pJTgWzCmI__7ofhhteNSOTJ3fZ9uNy31Y1XTnM/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values of "Products" and "Followers" using the built-in functions for Spreadsheet.

When I saw the HTML, the value of "Followers" can be directly retrieved using `=IMPORTXML(B5,"//a[contains(@href,'followers')]")`. But is seems that the value of "Products" is shown by the Javascript. So in this case, I would like to retrieve both values by parsing the variables of Javascript.

#### Sample formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(B5,"//script"),"item_count\\"":(\d+),\\""follower_count\\"":(\d+),"),"")),","))
```

- The URL of `https://shopee.ph/fitme.ph` is put in the cell "B5".
- The flow of this formula is as follows.

  1. Retrieve the Javascript using `IMPORTXML`.
  2. Retrieve values of "Products" and "Followers" using the regex of `item_count\\"":(\d+),\\""follower_count\\"":(\d+),` with `REGEXEXTRACT`.
  3. Remove the empty rows using `TEXTJOIN` and `SPLIT`.

#### Result:

[image]

#### References:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)
- [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)
- [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992)
- [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)

Comment: @Rojo Salas Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. By the way, in my proposal, the values are directly retrieved from the variable of Javascript. When I tested this several times, I could confirm that the regex in this answer could be used. But if the structure of variable is changed, the regex might be required to be modified. Please be careful this.